# Derivatives of the eikonal

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Let $y$ be an extremal function of the functional
$$J[y]=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} L(x, y(x), y'(x)) \mathrm{d}x$$
So it satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}=0$$
If we then substitute this $y$ into the original functional, we get the eigonal:
$$S(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_1)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} L(x, y(x), y'(x)) \mathrm{d}x$$
Which is now the function of $x_1, x_2, y_1=y(x_1), y_2=y(x_2)$. Then we have that
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial x_2}=-E(x_2)$$
And
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial y_2}=p(x_2)$$
Where
$$p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}$$
And
$$E=py'-L$$

**Question:** How to show these identities with differentiating $S$ directly?

I've seen the derivation with discretization, but I would like to do it this way. I tried to apply the Leibniz integral rule:
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial x_2}=L(x_2)+\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\partial L}{ \partial x_2} \mathrm{d}x$$
But I could not show that
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\partial L}{ \partial x_2} \mathrm{d}x=-p(x_2)y'(x_2)$$

Comment: There is a heuristic proof in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you, I will read it.

Comment: @Qmechanic It was perfect, thank you again!